# USB drive works only in one port

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro, usb

I have an old Kingston 2 GB USB flash drive.  I believe it was bought in 2006.

When I plug it into the right hand side USB port of a 2012 retina MacBook Pro, nothing happens. When I plug it into the left hand side port, it works fine.

Does this indicate a problem with the computer and its ports?  Does it indicate a problem with the USB drive?

All other devices I tried worked with both the left and right hand side USB port.

Answer (score 1):

System Management Controller (SMC)

Reset the SMC by following the instructions below, that should restore the power to the port:

1.Shut down the computer.
2.Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to the Mac if its not already connected.
3.On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
4.Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
5.Press the power button to turn on the computer.

Note: The LED on the MagSafe power adapter may change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC.